# ActiveRecord: How to look for records where boolean field is not true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How would I do a combination of the 2 queries below?

```
    1.9.3-p484 :003 > u = User.where(guest: false).count
       (2.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`guest` = 0
     => 0 
    1.9.3-p484 :004 > u = User.where(guest: nil).count
       (2.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`guest` IS NULL
     => 4150
```

I want to grab users that either have a nil or false value for the guest column (in one statement).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
User.where(guest: [false, nil]).count
```

This will generate query like below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE (("users"."guest" = 'f' OR "users"."guest" IS NULL))
```

or

```
User.where.not(guest: true).count
```

This will generate query like below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."guest" != 't')
```

The second one will take lesser time than the first one.

Comment: Be careful, .where.not(guest: true) query may ignore nil values of guest, i.e. may be equal to where (guest: false). At least it is in Rails 4.1 + Postgres. See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11702

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
   User.where("guest = 'f' OR guest IS NULL").count
```

For a boolean field, record would be saved with guest field as `t` (for true) or `f` (for false) value.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the sql way to accomplish this as there is no direct method for `OR` is implemented yet in rails

```
u = User.where('guest = ? OR guest IS ?', false, nil).count
```